# Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (MySQL DB connection error from Intellij)

Tags: java, mysql, config

UPDATE

I am trying to setup a Spring boot project using JPA and MySQL. I am having issues connecting to a simple MySQL DB with some tutorials I am following online. I am also trying to create a table called members and insert data using a script. I have the MySQL server running on my local right now and I get this error message:

```
ERROR 21205 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
```

Here is my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/members
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.profiles.active=dev
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.
```

This is my create.sql

```
CREATE TABLE MEMBERS(
  memberId INT NOT NULL,
  companyName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  companySize INT NOT NULL,
  primaryContact VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  state VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  netZeroTimeline INT NOT NULL,
  numCreditsDesired INT NOT NULL,
  --preferredOffsets VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  budget INT NOT NULL,
  carbonCreditId INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (memberId)
);
```

Lastly this is my member entity class (model)

```
package org.example.data.jpa.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member {

    Long memberId;
    String companyName;
    Integer companySize;
    String primaryContact;
    String city;
    String state;
    Integer netZeroTimeLine;
    Integer numCreditsDesired;
    //ArrayList<String> preferredOffsets = new ArrayList<String>();
    Double budget;
    Integer carbonCreditId;


    public Long getMemberId() {
        return memberId;
    }

    public void setMemberId(Long memberId) {
        this.memberId = memberId;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public Integer getCompanySize() {
        return companySize;
    }

    public void setCompanySize(Integer companySize) {
        this.companySize = companySize;
    }

    public String getPrimaryContact() {
        return primaryContact;
    }

    public void setPrimaryContact(String primaryContact) {
        this.primaryContact = primaryContact;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Integer getNetZeroTimeLine() {
        return netZeroTimeLine;
    }

    public void setNetZeroTimeLine(Integer netZeroTimeLine) {
        this.netZeroTimeLine = netZeroTimeLine;
    }

    public Integer getNumCreditsDesired() {
        return numCreditsDesired;
    }

    public void setNumCreditsDesired(Integer numCreditsDesired) {
        this.numCreditsDesired = numCreditsDesired;
    }

    public Double getBudget() {
        return budget;
    }

    public void setBudget(Double budget) {
        this.budget = budget;
    }

    public Integer getCarbonCreditId() {
        return carbonCreditId;
    }

    public void setCarbonCreditId(Integer carbonCreditId) {
        this.carbonCreditId = carbonCreditId;
    }

}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Is MySQL running on your computer (localhost)?

Comment: Hi Jesper, I cannot get to run on localhost right now with the application.properties file I have above. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm asking you if you have the MySQL database server running on your computer. Because your code is showing that you're trying to connect to a MySQL database server that's running on `localhost`. If the database server is not running, you'll get an error message similar to what you posted ("communications link failure"). So you need to check that the MySQL database server is indeed running, if not you need to start it before you run your program.

Comment: Is there a possibility that even if mysql is installed on your local machine, you have not started the mysql service?

Comment: @DAHUANGGO I have mysql installed on my machine and I started it, now I have a new problem with user@localhost connection. Check the question edits, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@user6952090 Then if there is no problem with the service, then according to your log, I personally think that there are only two reasons for the exception, the first is that your password is wrong, and the second is that your sql permissions are insufficient. If you have a database management system installed on a windows system, you can do the following:

1. Enter  `net stop mysql` in cmd.exe to stop the MySQL service
2. Enter the command line to go to the bin directory of mysql
3. Enter `mysqld --defaults-file="D:\MySQL\my.ini" --console --skip-grant-tables` in the bin directory
4. Open another cmd.exe, go to the bin directory of mysql, and enter: `mysql -uroot mysql`
5. Input: `update user set authentication_string=password('123456') where user='root';`
6. Refresh privileges: `mysql>flush privileges;`
7. `mysql>quit`
8. If you get an error when shutting down, type `mysqladmin -uroot -p shutdown [new_password]`
9. After changing the password, you can enter the command line: `net start mysql` to start the MySQL service, `mysql -uroot -p`, enter the password to enter mysql

Comment: Thanks for the level of detail here. When I get to step 4 I still run into this error message:  mysql -u root mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: And I can't even reset the password for the root user

Comment: @user6952090 If this is the case, then there may be nothing I can do, and if this can't be solved, you may need to turn to a more professional person.